# Quit PhD two years ago, now I want to go back?

Tags: phd, india

I quit my Ph.D. two years ago because of multiple reasons but largely due to my own naiveness over deciding to enroll for a Ph.D. I decided to do a Ph.D. without knowing anything about it. I wasn't prepared at all. I wrongly chose a lab that has a very poor vision for any scientific advancement. I foolishly chose a supervisor who had no idea what's going on in his lab. Once I understood this, I also became aware of my own weakness that has resulted in not getting me an ideal lab. This realization happened very lately and until now I had already developed a strong vision for my research project and my future career. And according to my plan, it wasn't that lab or supervisor who was going to help me to reach my goal. In academia, everything is connected, so if I wasn't going to be the best version of myself in Ph.D., the chances of finding a better opportunity after my Ph.D. was very less. So I decided to quit my Ph.D. and start it all over again; only this time knowing everything about a research career and how to excel in it. I wanted to become the best and for that, I had to work on myself first. So, a six month gap period was planned after leaving my Ph.D. But this gap time became much longer (because of some unfortunate circumstances); almost two years now and I have started feeling like a failure. I really want to go back and do some quality research. What is the best way to do it? 
P.S. I am from India and I am talking in terms of the Indian research institute.

Comment: What is wrong with just making application?